# Query database with flask by table

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I have a POSTGRES database that I already setup that has about a thousand or so tables (if there is a better way to organise this, that would be super helpful, I'm new to databases in general, but understand the basics).

I am trying to use `flask` to setup an API which will eventually be used by my vue app (and also probably available to the community of interest at large).

Ideally, I would like my api to look like: `stats/[table name]/[optional table data specific queries]`.

The tutorial and guides I've used or referenced have a database with one table that data is pulled from. Which is great, and I understand how to get that running, but when it comes to scaling up, I get lost.

rough outline of the db:

```
dbname
 |-table2
 |-table1
 |-...
 |-lastTable
```

The reason there are so many tables, is that it contains historical data from present day back to 2014, broken down by month and by settings eg 2017-04-gen5ou-0

Is flask the right choice for this?